# Saltstack - how to use Jinja logic based on saltenv

Tags: salt-stack

Is it possible to use Jinja to render a Salt state file, based on the salt environment?

Here's a simple example of setting a timezone for a server.  I want to set the timezone to New York if we are in the 'dev' environment, otherwise the timezone should be set to London.

**timezone.sls**

```
{% if saltenv == 'dev' %}
America/New_York
{% else %}
Europe/London
{% endif %}
  timezone.system
```

Executing `salt '*' state.sls timezone saltenv='dev'` gives the error:

```
Rendering SLS "base:timezone" failed: Jinja variable 'saltenv' is undefined; line 1
```

EDIT - as requested, here's the contents of the 'top.sls' file:

```
base:
  '*':
    - basic
    - git
```

Comment: Can you provide the sanitized contents of your top.sls  (usually found at `/srv/salt/top.sls`)

Comment: Just added this, although will this be relevant since I am running `state.sls` rather than `state.highstate` ?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for an answer to this:

```
{% set saltenv = salt.config.get('saltenv') %}
{% if saltenv == 'dev' %}
America/New_York
{% else %}
Europe/London
{% endif %}
  timezone.system
```

Comment: There are two other answers, posted many years ago. Please explain how yours improves on them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the minion should have some identification to know the role or environment.

Here's what you can do.

**Step 1 :** Assign grain to the minions e.g. grain name `circle` or `env` and value will be dependent on the type of minion i.e. `dev`, `live`, `staging` etc.

```
salt '*dev*' grains.setval circle dev
salt '*live*' grains.setval circle dev
```

**Step 2 :** In the state file you can do the following to get the `grain value` and based on the `circle` you can then run or assign values. Here I am executing different `cmd.run` based on the grain value

**test.sls**

```
{% set circle = salt['grains.get']('circle', '') %}

run_cmd:
  cmd.run:
{% if circle == 'dev' %}
    - name: 'echo dev'
{% else %}
    - name: 'echo live'
{% endif %}
```

Now if you run the following command it will run command based on the circle.

```
salt '*' state.sls test
```

This can also be done if you have absolute `id` for the minions e.g. if the dev minion id is always `dev-server` then you can run the following command and apply condition on that.

```
{% set id = salt['grains.get']('id', '') %}
```

Comment: *"The minion should have some identification to know <s>the role or</s> environment."* Ideally this identification of environment should be drawn from where this environment is already assigned to a minion (state `top.sls` file) without adding the second source of truth (in grains or embedded info in special minion name format) which has to be consistently changed every time.

Comment: Yes, but in that case one need to create separate states files for same state. i.e. If I want to set different mysql password for live and dev then either have the logic(if/else) inside the state file or two separate states and in top file add them to different envs.

Comment: Can you give an example with regard my code i.e. running different different command for different envs?

Comment: I simply guess the answer to the question is "no" - Salt does not provide `saltenv` variable for SLS files. It is impossible *"to use Jinja logic based on saltenv"*. Anything else (setting grains, assigning roles to minions through pillars, ...) which is synced with top file assignments of `saltenv` to minions is orthogonal/independent of it or, worse, repeating it (imagine 1K minions).

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a little late, but try this if this fulfill your requirements:

```
# check_saltenv.sls
{% import_yaml "top.sls" as defaults %}
{% set env = defaults.iteritems()|first %}
check_saltenv_file:
  cmd.run:
{% if 'prod' in env %}
    - name: echo 'prod' > /tmp/check_saltenv.txt
{% elif 'tb' in env %}
    - name: echo 'tb' > /tmp/check_saltenv.txt
{% elif 'dev' in env %}
    - name: echo 'dev' > /tmp/check_saltenv.txt
{% endif %}
```

Whereas I assume your production / testbed / development environment looks like this in your top.sls file:

Production -

```
# prod/top.sls
prod:
  'minion1':
    - whatever
```

Development -

```
# dev/top.sls
dev:
  'minion1':
    - whatever
```

Testbed -

```
# tb/top.sls
tb:
  'minion1':
    - whatever
```